# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I need your help. I get this error when I try to compile my application on my phone:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
```

Well, it says Button so, this is my code in my axml:

```
<Button
    android:text="Iniciar sesión"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:id="@+id/IniciarButton"
    android:background="@drawable/BotonLoginStyle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

and I have a xml file in my drawable folder call: BotonLoginStyle

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layout-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
          <solid android:color="#B40404"></solid>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#F5A9A9" android:startColor="#F5A9A9"></gradient>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#F5A9A9"></stroke>
          <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"></padding>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layout-list>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layout-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
          <solid android:color="#B40404"></solid>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#DF0101" android:startColor="#F5A9A9"></gradient>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#F5A9A9"></stroke>
          <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"></padding>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layout-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done some debugging to try to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Can you remove `android:background="@drawable/BotonLoginStyle"` and see if you still get the error?

Comment: When I remove the android:background="@drawable/BotonLoginStyle" it works :/

Answer (score 1):

I just followed four steps and the problem solved.

1. Clean Solution
   and AppData/xamarin/zips
2. Remove installed apk from mobile devices.
3. Remove Mono Shared Runtime from mobile devices
4. Rebuild solution

Comment: This worked for me. However, it was only possible on the emulator.
How can I remove Mono Shared Runtime from a device during app installation?
My apk has been uploaded to play store. Is there a way to make it remove the user's mono runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've removed `<layout-list>` and I put this `<layer-list>`and it **works**. Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

`android:background="@drawable/BotonLoginStyle"`

and try again this drawable or use other drawables.